# CSS Changing background-color with input type="color"?

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to do a webpage that at least has one color input and each time that color is changed, the background-color changes to that same color, live, without refreshing the page.

Comment: have u tried anything??

Comment: @Hiral No, because I don't know how to do it.

Comment: okay so mean input? that it is the font color right? also what it is the idea, pre defined colors or random?

Comment: @jycr753 Font color no, background-color. There must be a `<input type="color">`, and the background-color of the body changes at the same time as you change the input. No pre-defined colors neither random colors. The user has the ability to put any color that he wants to the background, just choosing a color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

JS:

```
$("#color").change(function(){
    var clr = $(this).val();
    $("body").css("background-color",clr);
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="color" id="color"/>
```

[Here is the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/E8C22/)